# Why does it ask me to input a string even after guessing the right string

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""

while guess != secret_word:
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

print("Bravo, you've guessed it right!")
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine here both in Python 3.4 and 3.7.1. Can you provide a picture of your code and terminal?

Comment: @Deathraider26 You can use 4 spaces in-front of each line of code to get it to format as code.

Comment: Please edit your question title.

Comment: I tried running the same program in Spyder and it worked. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Your original code worked for me on python. You could potentially try getting rid of leading and trailing spaces to make it more robust.

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""

while guess.strip() != secret_word:
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

print("Bravo, you've guessed it right!")
```

If you are using a Python 2 Interpreter it would not work as well due to syntax changes; therefore, you could edit your code to be Python 2 compatible. Or you may be calling the wrong terminal in the command line, to make sure that it is python three you can do usually do `python3 my_program.py` to explicitly use python 3.

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""

while guess != secret_word:
    guess = raw_input("Enter your guess: ")

print "Bravo, you've guessed it right!"
```

Cheers!

Comment: i'm using Python 3

Comment: @Deathraider26 Have you tried `python3 my_program.py`.

Comment: I tried running the same program in spyder and it worked. Weird!